# How to make multiple occurences of the same item have a different value from the first occurence?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a database that looks like this:

```
label_id, scan_type, scan_cost
```

And some rows that look like this:

```
001, A40, 70
001, A40, 70
002, A40, 85
003, A40, 85
003, A40, 85
```

I need to produce a result set that looks like this:

```
001, A40, 70
001, A40, 0
002, A40, 85
003, A40, 85
003, A40, 0
```

That is, any multiple occurrence of the same `label_id` then the `scan_cost` column needs to be set to 0, but the first occurrence of each `label_id` the value needs to remain untouched.

The `label_id` are not sequential if that changes anything.

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour in SQL? Note the SQL dialect is T-SQL, Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: Do you actually _need_ the duplicate rows returned at all?  ie rather than just zeroing the `scan_cost` for those rows, just don't include those subsequent rows?

Comment: Also, in your input examples `scan_cost` is always the same in every row, for any given `label_id`.  Is this the case across the entire dataset?

Comment: Nope, it could change. And yes I do need the duplicate rows to be included. Whats happening is, each scan has a cost, but the user only gets charged once per label_id. So by setting the scan_cost to 0 on all the other rows except the first, I can SUM() the scan_cost column and present the correct amount to charge the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This query returns what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
    label_id
,   scan_type
,   CASE WHEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY label_id ORDER BY scan_type)=1
        THEN scan_cost
        ELSE 0
    END
FROM test
ORDER BY label_id, scan_type
```

The idea behind this solution is to *partition* the data by `label_id`, and use [the `ROW_NUMBER` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to decide which data to keep.

I used `scan_type` in the `ORDER BY` sub-clause, which is not ideal. If your actual table has a column with data that is better suited to determine what row is first, e.g. a timestamp column, you should use that other column instead. The second column in the outer `order by` needs to be the same as the column in the inner `order by`.

Here is a link to this query on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/494fa/6).

Comment: You're missing an ORDER BY, or the results *can* come out wrong

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi I added the `order by` to the end, and mentioned some considerations regarding the inner `order by`. Thanks!

Comment: I think you missed the point. SQL Server can row_number one way and return your final result set in a completely different way. Since your partition is 'label_id' and the ORDER BY is single-column, the result won't look `correct` if the scan_cost is not on the first row, which was the whole purpose of the question.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi The data lacks a good column to do an ordering inside a partition, that's why I added a paragraph in my first edit saying that the `scan_type` is not a good choice, and a time stamp would have been better.

Comment: I think in this non tie-breaking situation, you actually need to retain the row number and `ORDER BY label_id, rownum` at the outer query to be accurate. Yes by outer I mean 2 levels are required

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi I think adding an extra level to the query would be an overkill: I'm nearly certain that OP's actual data has a decent tie-breaker column or a group of columns, so he should be able to do it with a single nesting level.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you are correct, the row also contains a scan_date column that can be used as a tiebreaker. Thanks for this solution by the way, it works perfectly!